# Register notification template from App Backend to Azure notification Hub

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to register a template in the Azure Notification Hub from my App Backend but there's no documentation on how to actually do that and no documentation of the used classes.

I'm trying to create a `RegistrationDescription` which should create the template I created for GCM:

```
{
"data": {
    "msg": "$(property1)"
}
}
```

Therefore, I'm trying to use a `GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.gcmtemplateregistrationdescription.aspx) . However I don't see where I  can inject the template into this object.

Registering to the hub should be easy after being able to create the `GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription` and should look like this:

```
       NotificationHubClient hub = GetHubFromConfig();  
       GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription registration = CreateRegistration();

       hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
```

How can I inject the template in the hub? Is there a completely different way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could assign template body to corresponding property:

```
registration.BodyTemplate=new CDataMember(templateBody);
```

or just use constructor:

```
public GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription(string gcmRegistrationId, string jsonPayload)
```

where jsonPayload is your template body